# Is there a way to make TypeScript narrow a union type based on some boolean variable used as a hint for narrowing

Tags: typescript

```
type Callback = (item: number) => number;

const foo = (list: number[], value: Callback | number) => {
  return list.map(item =>
    typeof value === 'function'? value(item) : value
  );
};
```

The above code works fine. However I'd like to refactor it so `typeof` expression wouldn't be evaluating each time as the `list` array may be pretty large. So I rewrote this code with boolean variable used as below:

```
type Callback = (item: number) => number;

const foo = (list: number[], value: Callback | number) => {
  const isFn = typeof value === 'function';
  return list.map(item =>
    isFn? value(item) : value
  );
};
```

But I get the error:

> This expression is not callable.   Not all constituents of type
> `'number | Callback'` are callable.
> Type `'number'` has no call signatures. `ts(2349)`

Comment: How about `list.map(typeof value === 'function' ? value : item => value)`?

Comment: @kaya3 How about posting it as an answer?

Comment: It's too similar to the accepted answer, which I upvoted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `if` statement like this

```
const foo = (list: number[], value: Callback | number) => {
 if(typeof value === 'function')
   return list.map(item => value(item));
 return list.map(item => value);
};
```

Comment: Simpler to just write `list.map(value)` in this case.

Comment: Sadly your solution is inapplicable to my real code which is a bit more complicated (it has nested expressions). However your answer solves the above problem fine.

Answer (score 0):

Typescript is dumb in some occasions...
You should explicitly tell him which type it's gonna be.

```
type Callback = (item: number) => number;

const foo = (list: number[], value: Callback | number) => {
  const isFn = typeof value === 'function';
    return list.map(item =>
      isFn? (value as Callback)(item) : value
    );
};
```